# backbone required to create rich grails Interface?

Tags: grails, backbone.js

I'm learning grails and I'm looking to build some rich UIs with ajax. My question is whether or not a third party js library like backbone is required to achieve such a goal? I'm under the understanding that grails has some built in tags such as formremote etc, so I'm not sure why you would need backbone. Is grails capable of rich UI's out of the box, or is a third party library like backbone required?

Comment: This is a good question. But not for stackoverflow. There is no good answer, just opinions, different backgrounds, lots of emotions. Probably the deciding factor here is the type of team you have. Some teams lean towards keeping things on the backend, some teams prefer their backend light.

Comment: @fdreger, but is a library like backbone required to build rich UI's in grails? I have no experience in either, so I'm struggling to figure out what path to go down. Grails is new to our organization.

Comment: Also from what I can see, they don't have a mailing list and recommend using the stack exchange network, so I'm not really sure where to post this question.

Comment: stackoverflow is for technical question. Yours is philosophical. If you enter "rich ajax ui library" into google, you will see there are hundreds of technologies and libraries that are all valid alternatives. And of course you can also roll write your own or go without any library. Is it a good idea to use backbone with grails? there is no purely technical answer to that question. Depends on your _specific_ aims, team, company culture, organizational constraints etc. There are so many factors here, that frankly, the answer is probably in the realm of chaos.

Comment: @CodeJunkie, I can tell you me own experience. We've developed a Commercial System for my company using Grails and the libraries that we've used were JQuery, JQGrid (for tables), jquery-impromptu (for msgboxes), jwysiwyg (for an rich HTML editor), jeditable (for inline HTML edition) and other small JQuery libraries.  Besides that we've developed some taglibs to make easy our job. Therefore the answer to your question is: It's perfectly possible to develop a Rich UI in Grails using only JQuery + JQuery libraries.

Comment: Complementing: It's perfeclty possible and most importantly: Feasible to develop a Rich UI in Grails using only JQuery + JQuery libraries

Comment: @Cantoni if you were to do it all over again, would you have gone the same route? Or do you feel like you would have benefited from a frontend framework like backbone? Thanks for your incite.

Comment: Yeah @CodeJunkie I possibly would gone to the same route again. However, the next time I'll use extensively some Grails features like Templates and Taglibs, I have used this features but I could have used many more. These are powerful features that helps the developer to create a Rich UI and avoid copy and paste.